# Backbone.js: how to trigger certain function on certain page?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

im building an e-commerce website.

i want to implement the shopping cart system and checkout procedure system using backbone.js and backbone.localStorage.js

it's not a SPA(single page application).

i understood the whole website as one application so i write all the javascript codes in one file.

in the file, i write something like this:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //blah 

var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //blah

var Cart = Backbone.View.extend({
    showItems: function(){
        //blah
    },
    //blah

var OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //blah

var Order = Backbone.View.extend({
    //blah

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('app initialized');
        var items = new ItemList;
        var cart = new Cart({collection: items});
        var orderModel = new OrderModel({id: 1});
        var order = new Order({ model: orderModel });
    }
});

var App = new AppView;
```

there's a showItems function in the cart view.

how should i trigger this function when user going to the checkout page?

i thought out two ways to do this

## 1

detect the current url is in checkout controller or something in the initialize function. (im using php codeigniter)

```
var Cart = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        if (document.URL.split('/')[1]=='checkout'){
            this.showItems(); 
        }
    }
```

## 2

put a hidden input in the checkout page

```
<input type='hidden' name'action_type' val='checkout' />
```

and detect it in the initialize function.

```
var Cart = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        if ($('input[name="action_type"]')=='checkout'){
            this.showItems(); 
        }
    }
```

but either way is a little bit ugly to me.
because if i need to trigger many different functions according to certain pages, then the the initial function would be like this

```
var Cart = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        if ($('input[name="action_type"]')=='checkout'){
            this.showItems(); 
        else if ($('input[name="action_type"]')=='filling_order_information'){
            //blah
        }
        else if ($('input[name="action_type"]')=='confirm_bill'){
            //blah
        }
```

which is ugly to me, and i think it's not what an initialize function should do. this's not initialization, it's a choosing process. there should be another place to do the choosing process.

i want to know

1. is there any other solutions?
2. or i totally use backbone.js in a wrong way. because i shouldn't understood the whole website as one application. if so, how to use backbone.js in a proper way in my situation?

im appreciate for any replies.

thank you all and im sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you can use Backbone.Router .

You can create different view for different usage. such as

```
var cartItem=new Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
    this.render(); 
}
var orderInfomation=new Backbone.View.extend({....})
```

And then you can use create a Router to render different view.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `val()` call in there? I don't think comparing a jQuery object with a string will work out that well.

Comment: thank you guys, i think router is exactly whay i need!

Comment: You are welcome . If you have any question about Backbone jQuery or something , we can exchange experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like Backbone.Marionette which got a more structured way to initialize the whole thing for you? Backbone.Marionette is available at http://marionettejs.com/

Comment: Marionette is a clumsy overworked system for something as simple as just showing a particular view.. Which is basically exactly what the router is for.